# Community Login Flow Causes Error Resetting Password

Tags: visualforce, flow, visual-workflow, community

We are attempting to implement a login flow on our community site for the Community Knowledge User profile. The flow works well with the exception of when someone goes to change their password. The new password link is generated properly, but when the user clicks the link they receive in their email to reset their password, they get a notification saying their password has already been changed and it effectively locks them out of the community site. I need to figure out a way to have a user go through the flow with the exception of when they need to reset their password. My understanding is that the "reset pw link" is entering the flow rather than going to the proper "create a new pw" screen. Any suggestions?

Comment: See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60547/reset-password-flow-for-communities-is-destructive?rq=1 to see if it answers your question.

Comment: I saw that post. Doesn't look like there's much of a solution at this point. Was hoping some might have fresh ideas.

Comment: @ErikEitel The reason I edited the two tags out is they have nothing to do with Community login or resetting passwords.

Comment: @ErikEitel That's why I didn't mark your question as a duplicate and asked instead if answered your question. I've seen this issue raised both here and on the Success Community and I think I have something that will point you to a solution.

Comment: @JesseMilburn I am using a Login Flow on the community site -so that tag is relevant and the route of the issue. A visualforce landing page to circumvent the login screen on PW reset may be involved with the solution and I wanted other's feedback. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an image that was posted in the Success Community as part of this thread in the [Community Implementation Group](https://success.salesforce.com/0F9300000001og8) regarding an issue with Self Registration from a Custom Login page. I believe it points the likely culprit of your issue.

[image: Community App Login Script]

What you'll notice is that `forgotPasswordURL` isn't prepended with `/community`. I believe it should read `"/community/ForgotPassword"`. That would explain why users can't get to the right location to reset their passwords for your community or site.

In essence, I believe you need to check your site/community login flow and controller to make certain everything is being pointed to the correct pages and that those pages are set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks! At current, I'm using the  standard login page - just hijacking the login with a login flow - I may have to look into a custom login process all together and double check the urls. Thanks for the feedback!